# How can Boomi Custom Connector Read Multiple Parameter Without using payload?

Tags: connector, boomi

Thank you for checking my question,

I'm developing a Boomi custom connector which consumes Restful API.

I have implemented the GET operation which receives only 1 ID parameters from User and QUERY operation which requests multiple parameters based on response profile and filtered expressions.

However, for API get request with multiple path parameters are required, both GET and QUERY operations seems not suitable.

For example: users//productTypes/

The above endpoint needs 2 parameters "userID" and "productTypeID"

I have implemented the EXECUTE operation and import an input profile with 2 parameters. The connector worked but it's not fully what I expect.

[EXECUTE operation no parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOolN.png)

[EXECUTE operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re4YD.png)

My expectation is to develop an operation with the same behaviour with GET operation.

After importing response profile, Connector prompts the user with a warning sign about missing parameters
Adding parameters in the parameter tab should be the only way to make the operation work
The connector will not require any input profile from the payload.
The purpose of these requirements is to improve user experience and avoid confusion on how to add the parameters.

[GET operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIpDH.png)

So my questions are:

- Which type of operation should I use for the above requirements/expectation?
- How to require multiple parameters with the warning sign, and if possible not to consume the payload/request profile

If you can attach related resource to implement those features, that would be great.

Thank you

Bryan